# OpenFrameworks: Move "camera" trough ofVbo?

Tags: 3d, openframeworks

I have a 3 dimensional shape drawn with an ofVbo and I would like to move trough it (like you'd move trough a space in a first person shooter). I thought I should use an ofCamera for this but I'm wondering if that would be a good solution, and I'm even starting to doubt if it's possible at all?

The openFrameworks documentation isn't very helpful and I have searched the web extensively but I'm still completely in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll be able to find what you're looking for [here](http://www.openframeworks.cc/documentation/3d/ofEasyCam.html). They created a very simple interface to moving around your app in 3d space.